# Use variable from lightning:recordEditForm in aura:if / ternary statement

Tags: lightning-recordeditform

I want to conditionally render one of the fields from recordEditForm. I've already done with attributes that are outside of form, but this time I want to bind the directly.

Thinking something like this along the lines:

```
<aura:attribute name="myBooleanAttribute" type="Boolean" access="private"/>
<lightning:recordEditForm
                onsuccess="{!c.redirect}"
                onsubmit="{!c.showSpinner}"
                onload="{!c.hideSpinner}"
                onerror="{!c.hideSpinner}"
                recordId="{!v.recordId}"
                objectApiName="Opportunity">
                    <lightning:inputField fieldName="SomeBoolean__c" value="{!v.myBooleanAttribute}"/>
                    <lightning:inputField class="{!v.myBooleanAttribute?'':'slds-hide'}" fieldName="Move_in_Date__c"/>
        </lightning:recordEditForm>
```

However this doesn't seem to bind them both ways...

Comment: Can you clarify a bit as what issue you are facing?

Comment: I want to render one field based on DB state or when user clicks on checkbox (SomeBoolean__c). It seems recordEditForm can only push data into inputField but I am looking for workaround.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's one way you can achieve it by utilizing `onchange` event on your boolean input field. The `value` attribute will not have an effect here, it will just override the value of your input field.

So to get this done, you will need to:

- Remove the `value` attribute
- Introduce an `onchange` and assign an `aura:id` to the field
- Utilize `aura:if` to re-render other field based on the selection

The component then looks as:

```
<lightning:inputField aura:id="chkbox" fieldName="SomeBoolean__c" onchange="{!c.onCheckBoxChange}"/>

<aura:if isTrue="{!v.myBooleanAttribute}">
    <lightning:inputField fieldName="Move_in_Date__c" />
</aura:if>
```

And then in the JS controller, update the attribute's value to be re-rendered

```
onCheckBoxChange : function(component, event, helper) {

    // will reset the value of the attribute to re-render the input field on component

    component.set("v.myBooleanAttribute", component.find("chkbox").get("v.value"));
},
```

Comment: Sorry, that doesn't work on init when SomeBoolean__c is already true.

Comment: Just set the attribute on `onload` of the record edit form and it will work.

Comment: Yep thats what I did. Also used conditional `slds-hide` class rather than aura:if.

Comment: Absolutely there could be other ways for sure but based on your question the approach I mentioned works too.